# Specified cast is not valid ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I have LINQ query getting some data from entity framework connection. I am passing the data from the controller to the View. When running the code i get the error 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Here is my LINQ statement

```
var MeltAreaInformation =
    new
    {
        Striko1 = (from item in db.tbl_dppITHr where item.ProductionHour >= SelectedDateDayShiftStart && item.ProductionHour <= SelectedDateDayShiftHr25End select item).Sum(x => x.Striko1) ?? 0,

              Striko2 =
             (from item in db.tbl_dppITHr
              where item.ProductionHour >= SelectedDateDayShiftStart && item.ProductionHour <= SelectedDateDayShiftHr25End
              select item).Sum(x => x.Striko2) ?? 0,

              Striko3 =
             (from item in db.tbl_dppITHr
              where item.ProductionHour >= SelectedDateDayShiftStart && item.ProductionHour <= SelectedDateDayShiftHr25End
              select item).Sum(x => x.Striko3) ?? 0,

              Striko4 =
             (from item in db.tbl_dppITHr
              where item.ProductionHour >= SelectedDateDayShiftStart && item.ProductionHour <= SelectedDateDayShiftHr25End
              select item).Sum(x => x.Striko4) ?? 0,

              Striko5 =
             (from item in db.tbl_dppITHr
              where item.ProductionHour >= SelectedDateDayShiftStart && item.ProductionHour <= SelectedDateDayShiftHr25End
              select item).Sum(x => x.Striko5) ?? 0,

              Induction1 =
             (from item in db.tbl_dppITHr
              where item.ProductionHour >= SelectedDateDayShiftStart && item.ProductionHour <= SelectedDateDayShiftHr25End
              select item).Sum(x => x.Inductotherm1) ?? 0,

              Induction2 =
             (from item in db.tbl_dppITHr
              where item.ProductionHour >= SelectedDateDayShiftStart && item.ProductionHour <= SelectedDateDayShiftHr25End
              select item).Sum(x => x.Inductotherm2) ?? 0,
    };


        ViewData["Striko2"] = MeltAreaInformation.Striko1.ToString();
```

Now When i run the application in debug and hover of the Var MeltAreaInformation you can see it has the following assigned to it.
[image]

The following is the Razor syntax that i am using to display the ViewData on the HTML page.

```
<table class="MeltTable">
<tr><th colspan="7">Total Weight Poured (kg's)</th></tr>
<tr><th>Striko 2</th><td class="MeltTableZero td @((int)ViewData["Striko2"] == 0 ? "red" : null)">@ViewData["Striko2"].ToString()</td></tr>
<tr><th>Striko 3</th><td class="MeltTableZero td @((int)ViewData["Striko3"] == 0 ? "red" : null)">@ViewData["Striko3"].ToString()</td></tr>
<tr><th>Striko 4</th><td class="MeltTableZero td @((int)ViewData["Striko4"] == 0 ? "red" : null)">@ViewData["Striko4"].ToString()</td></tr>
<tr><th>Striko 1</th><td class="MeltTableZero td @((int)ViewData["Striko1"] == 0 ? "red" : null)">@ViewData["Striko1"].ToString()</td></tr>
<tr><th>Striko 5</th><td class="MeltTableZero td @((int)ViewData["Striko5"] == 0 ? "red" : null)">@ViewData["Striko5"].ToString()</td></tr>
<tr><th>Induction 1</th><td class="MeltTableZero td @((int)ViewData["Inductotherm1"] == 0 ? "red" : null)">@ViewData["Inductotherm1"].ToString()</td></tr>
<tr><th>Induction 2</th><td class="MeltTableZero td @((int)ViewData["Inductotherm2"] == 0 ? "red" : null)">@ViewData["Inductotherm2"].ToString()</td></tr>
</table>
```

Can anyone shed some light on the problem. I have tried to manually assign the values and still i am getting the same issue.

Comment: Are all the return values definitely Int32?

Comment: Can you show all the ViewData assignments?

Comment: Hold up - you are `ToString()`ing the values in ViewData - you can't cast a string to an int...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewData["Striko2"] = MeltAreaInformation.Striko1.ToString();`

This is your problem - you put the values in the `ViewData` bag as strings and then try casting them in your view:

`@((int)ViewData["Striko2"] == 0 ? "red" : null)`

That is not going to happen! Either bag the values as their type (`int`) or don't cast them in the view (you can just write the strings without the cast) - your call

Comment: I also get the same issue at a different part of the code where the Razor is @ViewData["PumaShipped"] and its values are also not nulls

Comment: Can you post the line (and surrounding lines) in the View that the debugger breaks on and the associated Controller/ViewModel code?

Comment: it breaks on @ViewData["DVEuro5Shipped"]

Controller Code 

            var DVEuro5Product =
               new{

                   DVEuro5Shipped =
             (from item in db.tbl_dppITHr
              where item.ProductionHour >= SelectedDateDayShiftStart && item.ProductionHour <= SelectedDateDayShiftHr25End
              select item).Sum(x => x.DVE5Shipped) ?? 0}

Comment: Can you post the code in the original question (formatted) as it's easier to read, and also post the part where you put the items into the `ViewData` bag (`ViewData["xxx"] = value`), as much as possible - at a guess I'd say you are dropping an anonymous type in there and the values are not being made keys in the `ViewData` bag.